# Is it possible to exclude multiple sections from an entry search query?

Tags: search, sections, entrymodel, queries

I'm trying to build a search function that excludes results from certain sections all together. This is the code I was trying to use.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).section('not testimonials, not authors').id('not 2').order('score') %}
```

When I use just one section, it works fine:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).section('not authors').id('not 2').order('score') %}
```

Any thoughts on how I could construct this query?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The trick is to add `and` once before the first `not`

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).section('and, not this, not that') %}
```

Comment: in Craft 4.x you would write it the following way: `.section(['not', 'this','that','someOther'])`