# Search in section only

Tags: search, sections, include

How would I enable search in a single section only?

I want my search results template to be used regardless of which search option is used. Ideally I'm looking to pass another value from my search form to the search results to do

`{% paginate craft.entries.search(query).section(sectionPassedFromSearchForm).limit(5) as entries %}`

Comment: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/is-it-possible-to-exclude-multiple-sections-from-an-entry-search-query

Comment: Totally not following... obviously you can pass in the name of the section(s) you want to search, but I feel like I'm not understanding what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just pass the other value (i.e. the section handle) in to that template as GET or POST parameter and in the search results template grab the paramater and use it, as in your code.

If using GET, the url you'd construct would be something like:

```
http://whatever.com/search?query=blah&sectionHandle=blah2
```

or with POST you might use e.g. a radio for the section option with the `name` being `sectionHandle` and the `value` being the actual handle of the chosen section.

Either way, in your template you then just:

```
{% set sectionHandle = craft.request.getParam(sectionHandle) %}
{% paginate craft.entries.search(query).section(sectionHandle).limit(5) as entries %}
```